# How to display my exact driver

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, games, steam

Does the current 415 nvidia driver have extensions? 415.xx or something? How do I display my exact installed driver using command line?  I am trying to use Steam Play for gaming and want to be sure I have the very latest updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No extensions (i.e. 415.xxx). To see which driver you're using, you might want to try

```
apt list --installed | grep nvidia
```

If you have 415 installed, you'd see the `nvidia-415` package. To see the latest available, you can `apt-cache search nvidia` or use the GUI. Open the application launcher and search for "Additional Drivers". That will check your hardware & search for compatible drivers. You can select the latest version from there.

Comment: Thanks, it does show what looks like an extension to me. Here is the result of the above command.

xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-415/bionic,now 415.18-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: My bad, I thought you just meant in the package name.